# Changing symbol by expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, qgsexpression

The same way we can define the color of symbols using expressions, do you know if we can change the symbol itself in QGIS 3.24?

In my situation, I use a layer *'OPTIONS'* to change values on the map, which show the information I want to see/export. But in some cases, I would like to have also different symbols.

It could be useful to change the symbol according to the content of a field.

```
CASE 
    WHEN "Field" = 1 THEN SYMBOL_1
    WHEN "Field" = 2 THEN SYMBOL_2
    WHEN "Field" = 3 THEN SYMBOL_3
END
```

The only solution I have in mind right now is to create different symbols for the same legend entry and play with the opacity to display the one I want. But I'm afraid it could slow the project.

Comment: The answer given by Mayo helped me to resolve my issue. I didn't know how to find the name of the symbols. The link you posted bring to a post which also address my issue indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set an expression by clicking the expression button as shown below.

[image]

Then click the **edit** option.

[image]

and calculate an expression that look like this, you can find the names of the symbols by hovering each symbol like in the first picture.

```
CASE 
   WHEN "Field" = 1 THEN 'square'
   WHEN "Field" = 2 THEN 'equilateral_triangle'
   WHEN "Field" = 3 THEN 'circle'
END
```

Comment: For more complex symbol you may use the same kind of expression with svg symbol